# How does the Ghost of Creuss' Flagship's enemy movement prevention ability work?

Tags: twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

The *Hil Colish* Flagship has a few abilities, but the last one isn't entirely clear to me.

> No other race may travel through the “D” wormhole, not even with Light/Wave Deflector.

Is this a general restriction, meaning that once my Flagship hits the table, enemies cannot move through *any* of the D-wormhole spaces?

Or is it just meant to clarify that enemy ships can't attack your Flagship through its own wormhole?

Or is the "Enemies can't move through the D-wormhole" a general rule, and is this a reminder of that rule?

I can't find a conclusive answer and the various Wikis and info sites seem to have different wordings on how exactly this ability works.

Answer (score 2):

**It is just a restriction on the flagship's wormhole.**

Here's the full text of the card:

> This ship generates a "D" wormhole in the system where it lies. When the ship moves, the "D" wormhole moves to the ship's destination system (the system in which the ship ends its movement)
>
> When the ship is destroyed, the “D” wormhole it generates disappears
>
> This ship may not use the “D” wormhole it generates
>
> (Note: No other factions may travel through the “D” wormhole, not even with the Light/Wave Deflector technology)

And the rules on the D wormhole in general:

> The Ghosts of Creuss have two separate Home Systems
> connected by a “D” Wormhole. Both of these systems are
> considered Home Systems for the purpose of card and game
> effects. During setup, the Ghosts of Creuss player only places
> the hexagonal tile in the galaxy. He places the non-hexagonal
> tile in front of him. Also, the “D” Wormhole is considered a
> Wormhole for the purposes of card and game effects.

The text in question is part of a parenthetical on the card, meaning that it's not an ability in it's own right but rather a clarification the other abilities.  As a result, I think it's reasonable to conclude that "No other factions may travel through the D worhmole" refers specifically to the D wormhole generated by the flagship and not to the other D wormholes on the board (the one on Creuss and on Creuss gate).

The card would be clearer if it said "No other faction may travel through the D wormhole **it generates**".